# Why does GetLastError return ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE?

Tags: c, windows, dll

I have trouble understanding what happens to the `getlasterror` function in the below code. 
My `dll` is a valid one and `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` do not fail, but `GetLastError` returns:

> 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE).

The code:

```
int main()
{
    const char* mydll = "mydll.dll";
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;


    hinstLib = LoadLibraryA(mydll);

    if (hinstLib) {

        int rez = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
        
        if (rez) {
            printf(" SUCCESS but Geterror:: %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: only if If the function fails exist sense call `GetLastError()` (if api set it). if `FreeLibrary` return true - result of `GetLastError` undefined

Comment: simply when `FreeLibrary` is ok - it not set last error and not reset it to 0. as result you view some trash and old value here, from previous internal calls

Comment: What happens if you put another  `printf(" SUCCESS but Geterror:: %d\n", GetLastError());` right before `int rez = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);`?

Comment: this will be the output :    SUCCESS but Geterror:: 6
 SUCCESS but Geterror:: 6

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the documentation for [`FreeLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibrary) indicating (or even suggesting) that the calling thread's error code will be set on a *successful* call. Thus, your call to `GetLastError()` following a non-zero (successful) return from `FreeLibrary()` would *seem* to be returning an 'arbitrary' value.

From the `GetLastError()` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror):

> The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that
> sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function
> sets the last-error code. Most functions that set the thread's
> last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also
> set the last-error code when they succeed. If the function is not
> documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this
> function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set;
> some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do
> not.

You could *probably* verify this by *explicitly* setting your thread's error code *before* calling `FreeLibrary()`:

```cpp
    //...
    SetLastError(0); // Set last error code
    int rez = FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
    //...
```

**EDIT:** If, even with this in place, you are still seeing a 'consistent' value for the last error, then it is likely that your `mydll.dll` is *itself* calling a WinAPI function that fails (with the reason/error being `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`), from code executed in the `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` section of its `DllMain()` procedure. However, if that procedure still returns `TRUE`, then the `FreeLibrary()` function will also return `TRUE`(i.e. it will signal that your DLL *was* unloaded).

Comment: *explicitly setting your thread's error code before calling* - in general case - api can be enough complex and do internal many calls for another api. some of this calls can fail and set last error. but whole top level api call not fail. as result possible that `GetLastError` return value will be undefined even if you set last error to 0 before api call

Comment: Still returns 6 after FreeLibrary

Comment: @RbMm It seems that the OP's test takes *your* side of the 'argument'! Hmm...

Comment: @AdrianMole - simply this is undefined. for concrete example - if `FreeLibrary` finally unload dll (this can be or not, depend from dll reference count) - will be it entry point called with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` (again if dll have entry point). here custom dll code can make some api calls. some of it can fail and change last error code. but finally dll anyway will be unloaded and `FreeLibrary` return true. all what is possible say - no any sense call and check `GetLastError` if `FreeLibrary` return true.

Comment: @RbMm I agree entirely! I was adding my latest edit while you were posting your last comment.

Comment: *When the system calls the DllMain function with any value other than DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, the return value is ignored.*  so even if we return false on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` dll wil be unloaded